# ImportError: No module named httplib2, but httplib2 is installed

Tags: python

I know this may be somewhat of a duplicate, but the difference is that i have httplib2 installed, look:

```
    D4zk1tty@kali:~$ sudo apt-get install python-httplib2
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    python-httplib2 is already the newest version.
    python-httplib2 set to manually installed.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded
```

maybe it is not in the right directory?

here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    import httplib2
ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

Comment: could you please post the full traceback when trying to import the module?

Comment: Have you verified that the module is in one of the paths in `sys.path`?

Comment: @D4zk1tty Which python version are you using? Was it installed with `apt-get`/Software Center? Also what you get if you do `import sys; print sys.path` in the interpreter?

Comment: I did ls -l /usr/lib/python3.2 and found urllib, but I am not sure if that is the equivelent of httplib

Comment: @Salem, I did try that. the directory was /usr/lib/python3.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ubuntu python2/python3 modules are split in separated packages. So to install `httplib2` in  `python3` the correct command is

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-httplib2
```

Usually you can assume if there is any package named `python-???`, you also have `python3-???` (`python-django` is one example which don't have a python3 package available).

Comment: Thanks, it working now; all I have to do is learn the syntax XD

Comment: If this was the answer that solved your problem, I highly recommend marking it as such (click the check mark next to it).

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want to find out where something has been installed you can use either the find or location functions. Example here:

```
sudo find / | grep httplib2
```

Also, as far as checking which version of python (or anything else) you happen to be running, commands such as:

```
which python
```

can be invaluable to suss out where things have been installed and what your machine is actually doing when you run something in python. As a final note, you can always echo your system variables to see where your computer is looking:

```
echo $PATH
```

and adding things to your path can help with problems like these, especially if you're using the wrong python. You can change path as follows:

```
export PATH=path/to/bin:$PATH
```